# Warning: Illegal string offset 'image'

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, plugins

I am using [Skitter Slideshow plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-skitter-slideshow/) for wordpress, in the admin panel of this plugin at Media Library tab it shows the following warning:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\plugins\wp-skitter-slideshow\wp-skitter-slideshow.php on line 762 and 826
```

this problem appears when trying load new images in in the admin panel of this plugin ...

line 762 code

```
foreach($attachments as $i => $attachment) {

    $id = $attachment->ID;

    $style = (is_array($options_attachments['image']) && in_array($id, $options_attachments['image'])) ? ' style="opacity:0.3;"' : '';
```

line 826 code

```
foreach($attachments as $i => $attachment) 
{

    $id = $attachment->ID;

    if (is_array($options_attachments['image']) && in_array($id, $options_attachments['image'])) continue;
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Looks like `$options_attachments` is a string value and not an array.

Comment: @CBroe how to resolve this?

Comment: If it's not your code, then ask the developer of the plugin.

Comment: @CBroe I already raised the question at the support page of this plugin [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-illegal-string-offset-image) but I found in the support page that no one complained about this issue